# Link to How-to guide in articles is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, collectives, articles

When I click on the link in the article it leads to page 404.

[image]

The URL it leads to is:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/search?q=[how-to-guide]+is:article
```

When I click from the article list, the URL is working:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[how-to-guide]+is:article
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for logging this bug. The developers were made aware and it has been fixed now.

Comment: Looks like the search URL has been fixed, but it would make a lot more sense if the search also included `collective:"Whatever collective the article was in"` - I imagine someone clicking "how-to guide" in a collective is mostly after other guides in the same collective